# Is there a way to track a RFID using the RFID reader?

Tags: windows, smartcard, rfid

I have a long range RFID reader together with the RFID. Is there any possibility to track the RFID? Thanks. I use vb.net as my programming language for saving the tag to the database.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this question as off-topic.  Please edit your question to more firmly define it as a programming question (as it stands, it's more of a physics question)

Answer (score 1):

The tag only reply with an id, but not with an timestamp when the id started sending, right?. You need the time to measure speed. With the time and knowing which antenna received the answer of the tag and the time when the reader started asking for tags you could make a rough assumption about distance and maybe direction of travel.
For really tracking movement you need to know the building environment and needs to have more than just one reader.
A RFID tag is not a GPS transponder

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. Time? I don't fully understand this sir. Can you elaborate more if you don't mind? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For tracking movement you need at least x,y coordinates and time. Without time you cannot calculate speed. When you know how long an object took to move from 3,3 to 30,3 you can determine the average speed it had while moving between those two points. normal passive tags usually only transmit an id. Tracking would be roughy possible if you had the range of the reader, the time the reader issued an read-event and the time the tag responded. the difference in time from issuing the read-event, the tag-answering and the reception of the answer at the reader a speed could be calculated

Comment: with additional information from the readers antenna you could then make a rough assumption of in which part of the room the object movement occurred and how fast it was.

Comment: I think they are RFID tags that also provide a timestamp, but the minimum functionality is providing an ID by radio frequency=> RFID. The more complex a tag is the more expensive it becomes so you should not assume that every tag provides you with timestamp information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. So I will primarily focus on time for tracking right? But how can I calculate that since the reader can only read the tag. And also, how can I know if the tag has a timestamp information? And, let me just clarify. I am only using one reader because I can't afford to buy another one.